# Inferring generic parameters from generic types

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

I'm running into an issue when trying to infer generic parameters on generic types that are specifically objects:

```ts
type Box <T extends object> = { value: T; }

function set <T extends object>(box: Box <T> , newValue: T): void {
  box.value = newValue;
}

const bbox: Box <{ foo: string }> = {
  value: {
    foo: "bar"
  }
};

set(bbox, {
  foo: "baz"
}); // OK as expected
set(bbox, 42); // ERR as expected
set(bbox, {
  bar: "baz"
}); // ERR as expected

set(bbox, {}); // OK, unexpected
set(bbox, { /* no autocomplete/intellisense is given here for valid props */ });
```

If you provide `{}` as the parameter, TypeScript infers `{}` as a valid type for the function. This also means that in an editor, no autocomplete is given for the fields of the specified object type, since the `{}` matches all objects.

Is there an order as to how TypeScript infers generic parameters (i.e. `newValue`'s inference overrides `Box<T>`'s inference, and any object is assignable to `{}`)? If so, is there a way to avoid this?

---

You can partially solve this issue by adding an extra parameter:

```ts
function set <T, TN extends T> (box: Box <T> , newValue: TN): T {
  box.value = newValue;
  return newValue;
}

const bbox: Box <{ foo: string }> = {
  value: {
    foo: "bar"
  }
};

set(bbox, {}); // ERR, expected
set(bbox, { /* still no autocomplete/intellisense */ });
```

However, you still do not receive any autocomplete/IntelliSense. I would guess it's because of the `extends`, and how you're no longer looking for `T` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about how autocomplete works to tell you exactly why it doesn't work in your case; my intuition is that it hasn't fully committed to the generic type inference.  One workaround that forces it to commit to the inferred type is to change `set` into a [curried function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) like this:

```
const intelliSet = <B extends Box<{}>>(box: B) => 
  (newValue: B['value']) => set(box, newValue);

intelliSet(bbox)( { foo: 'bar' }); // note the second function call
intelliSet(bbox)( { /* autocomplete works here */ });
```

---

I don't know if there are non-workaround solutions.  I'd be inclined to file a suggestion issue on GitHub, if one doesn't already exist.  [This one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17654) is possibly relevant, especially [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17654#issuecomment-320886377).  Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can make TypeScript to do inference starting from the first argument if you declare `set` like this:

```
function set<T extends object, B extends Box<T>>(box: B, newValue: B['value']): void {
    box.value = newValue;
}
```

No idea if it fixes autocomplete issue though.